# print break line after n number of iterations

Tags: php

The goal is to "break line" after each split.

**I have two arrays:**

```
$split = [4, 2, 4];
$courses = ['HTML', 'JS', 'CSS', 'VueJS', 'ReactJs', 'PHP', 'Ruby', 'Python', 'Java', 'C#'];
```

As you can see I have the first `array` called split, and the second `array` called courses, I want to add `<br>`   after each split

I want to loop over `$courses` and after the 4 items I print `<br>`. Also after 2 items I print another `<br>`

Note: I can have more values in my `$split` array, that's why I don't want to use

```
foreach($courses as $key => $value){
   echo $value;
   if ($key == 4 OR $key == 2){
      echo '<br>';
   }
}
```

My code is not working fine because I can't use a lot of `OR` with `if statements`, because I can have a lot of split in my `$split` `array`

Is there any clean and best way to loop over `$courses` and print `<br>` after `4` loop and after `2` and after `4` and so on, it depends on how many split I have in my `$split`

Comment: Well you are going to have to process the split array somehow, did you try anything like that yet

Answer (score 0):

This will get the job done, bear in mind that arrays start at 0, not 1. so it would break on the 3rd and 5th item not 2nd and 4th.

More on [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
<?php

$split = [4, 2, 4];
$courses = ['HTML', 'JS', 'CSS', 'VueJS', 'ReactJs', 'PHP', 'Ruby', 'Python', 'Java', 'C#'];
foreach($courses as $key => $value){
    echo $value;
    if (in_array($key, $split)) {
        echo '<br>';
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: will not work because i can have  two times  2 or two or more times 4

Comment: in_array will still return true, 2 exists (even if duplicated)

Answer (score 0):

You need to track next items order after found it.

```php
<?php

$split = [4, 2, 3];
$courses = ['HTML', 'JS', 'CSS', 'VueJS', 'ReactJs', 'PHP', 'Ruby', 'Python', 'Java', 'C#'];

$split_position = $reIndexValue = 0;
$elements = [];

foreach($courses as $index => $name) {
    $reIndexValue++;

    if(is_int($split_position) && $reIndexValue == $split[$split_position]) {
        
        $name = $name.'<br>';
        $split_position = isset($split[$split_position + 1])? ++ $split_position : false;
        $reIndexValue = 0;
        
    }
    
    $elements[] = $name;
}

echo implode (' ',$elements);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will first echo a line break after 4 iterations, then it will echo a line break after 2 more iterations, and then it will echo another line break after 4 more iterations. (The code will continue for any specified sequence in the $split array)

```
<?php

$split = [4, 2, 4];
$courses = ['HTML', 'JS', 'CSS', 'VueJS', 'ReactJs', 'PHP', 'Ruby', 'Python', 'Java', 'C#', 'Pascal', "Fortran"];

$count = 0; //Counting the times we looped using a seperate variable
foreach($courses as $key => $value){
    echo $value." ";
    $count += 1; //Increase count
    if ($split[0]==$count) { //If the $count is similar to the first variable in $split array,
        echo '<br>';
        $count=0; //Reset $count back to 0
        array_shift($split); //Remove the already performed first variable from array
    }

    //without the following block, code will give you an "Undefined offset" notice 
    if (count($split)==0){
        array_push($split, -1);//Add a dummy variable (-1) that will never be tested. 
    }
 }

?>
```

I added 2 other variables "Pascal" and "Fortran" into the $courses array to test the behavior